# Service Bus Queue nightmare. Messages disappeared

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, cancellation-token

We are running a cloud service on two different​ instances. This cloud service spins up a receiver on a service bus queue. This receiver is configured as:
1. Peek and lock mode
2. Auto complete = true
3. RenewLockTimeout = 10 mins
4. MaxConcurrentMessages = 1
5. PrefetchCount = default (should be 0)

For what I know this means that a maximum of two messages are processed at the same time (one per instance) and messages are automatically removed from the queue as soon as the message handler is completed.

Now, few days ago Azure decided to update our instances. I've seen from the log that at 18.18 the first instance was requested​ to stop. At 18.24 the instance was stopped and at 18.27 came back online. At 18.28 the second instance was requested to stop and at 18.35 it was back online.

Seven messages has been enqueued at 18.23. One of them produced the expected record on the DB (i.e. the handler was executed successfully). The other 6, NO. Dead letter queue is enabled, but empty.

In theory my code should stop receiving messages as soon as the roles enter in the OnStop method. A cancellation token is canceled and the message handler is "paused" introducing a delay for 10 mins (so, for what I know, the message shouldn't be completed and then it should be processed again). So I cannot say If the first message has been processed by the first or the second machine. But it was processed. And I'm sure that the other 6 were in the queue.

If there is an exception in the message handler, I send it to Application Insights and rethrow (to let the handler fail and process the message again). But I have no evidence of that.

I think I've checked everything, and I cannot tell why those messages disappeared. In your experience, what should that be?

Is that normal that Azure waits for 5 minutes after shutting down? Or is that a signal that I'm not honoring the cancellation token?

Thanks

Comment: What's the MaxDeliveryCount on that queue and have you checked the Transfer DLQ?

Comment: MaxDeliveryCount is 10. What's the Transfer DLQ?

Comment: Have a post about it: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/the-secret-brotherhood-of-message-counts

Comment: No, no message neither in the Transfer queue nor in the Transfer DLQ.

Comment: Hmmm, then I'm not sure what's going on. Usually messages do not disappear w/o any traces unless that connection string & entity is used by some other code... is that an option?

Comment: I'd say no. If you agree with what I wrote, then it's necessarily a code bug. Probably some exception is swallowed and the message is completed without any trace.

Comment: W/o seeing the code, hard to assume anything. Saying that, I have seen done peculiar behavior with ASB. But then it would disagree messages, not lose them. Perhaps sharing that code would help.

Comment: Is there a chance that the lost messages were enqueued with future timestamp via ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc? In this case you won't see those messages anywhere until that time. I am guessing though you would have thought of that, and have to say I have not seen ASB losing messages so far. It's more likely this is an application start/stop error handling bug.

Comment: No way. I'm not using ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC. :-(
It must be an application bug.

Answer (score 1):

As we know, the receiver can read a message from a Service Bus queue in two different ways:  [ReceiveAndDelete and Peek-lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#receive-mode). The ReceiveAndDelete mode, if the receiver crashes before it finishes processing the message, the message will be lost. The Peek-lock mode, if the receiver crashes before it finishes processing the message and do not complete the message, the message will not be lost/disappear.

As others said, not seeing your code, it is hard to find the issue. If possible, please modify your code to set [OnMessageOptions.AutoComplete property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.autocomplete?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_OnMessageOptions_AutoComplete) to false, and explicitly call [Complete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_Complete) after the receiver finishes processing the message and creating record on your DB, and then check if it could solve the issue.

Comment: This is what I was going to do :-) I just wanted to check if there was something unknown to me that maybe caused this message loss. For what I see, everything is clear, so it must be a bug in my message handling procedure.

Comment: So you may set a like to Fei Han answer

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced similar symptoms with on a function app processing from a Service Bus Topic Subscription where messages seemed to be disappearing.

I was instantiating [ServiceBusClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.azure.servicebusclientbuilderextensions.addservicebusclient?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.AddServiceBusClient%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) via the [AzureClientServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAzureClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.azure.azureclientservicecollectionextensions.addazureclients?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.AzureClientServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAzureClients);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet-preview) in my function app startup. Inside the class where I was creating a ServiceBusReceiver in ReceiveAndDelete mode and calling the [ReceiveMessagesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.receivemessagesasync?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) method.

The problem seems to be with the ServiceBusReceiver hanging around supposedly dequeuing messages in the background (even after my function app had stopped!). The fix for this was to dispose of the Receiver once I was done with it.